# Creating a directory that can only be accessed by a program

Tags: python, encryption

I'm storing image files in a directory. To stop potential hackers I would need to restrict access to the files either by encrypting the images or stopping direct access to the image directory.

I would rather not encrypt the image files as this makes things a lot more complex.

Is there a way to restrict access to a directory or file to only be accessed by a python program?

Comment: You can change the file and directory permissions to some account that your Python program runs under, but you cannot specify a specific program that can access them. If a hacker compromises your Python program they then *must* be able to get the unprotected image files. There is just no solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please don't store the original image anywhere. Think of this as a password, except in this case it's a password that can't be changed by the user without a great deal of pain.

So you should take all the same measures that password system people take. Specifically, instead of storing the password, you should compute some kind of "salted hash" of the password, ideally with a random "pepper" value. See [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) for terminology, and a list of things to do and not to do.

Ultimately, think of the downside: if **my** fingerprint data gets compromised on **your** web site, how does that affect me on other web sites?

If the answer is, "Now the hackers have my fingerprint(s) and can pretend to be me," then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: This was only for a school project, so don't worry about any users data getting breached, but you're right in a real life example I definitely wouldn't store the image. In the end I decided to use the method of collecting key points in the image and then encrypting them. I couldn't use a hash value because I wanted to have a 70% match threshold for the fingerprint, which I then increased to 80%, therefore a hash matching system would not have worked. Thanks for the answer, this sparked the idea for me.